# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Sätzen?

Tags: word-usage, standard-german

Kann mir jemand kurz erläutern, was der Unterschied der folgenden zwei Sätze ist?

> Die Möglichkeiten bestehen unter Einhaltung der Regelungen des zur Anwendung kommenden Rechnungslegungssystems.

> Die Möglichkeiten bestehen unter Einhaltung der Regelungen des anwendenden Rechnungslegungssystems.

Ich verstehe hier nicht den Teil von "zur Anwendung kommenden". Inhaltlicherweise ja, aber bin verwirrt wieso schreibt man es so, stattdessen einfache "anwendenden"?

Answer (score 2):

*Des anwendenden Rechnungslegungssystems* ist inhaltlich (nicht syntaktisch) inkorrekt. Systeme wenden nicht an, sie werden angewendet.

Möglich wäre *des angewandten Rechnungslegungssystems* oder *des verwendeten Rechnungslegungssystems*. Ob man diese Wortgruppen verwendet oder aber *des zur Anwendung kommenden Rechnungslegungssystems*, ist eine reine Stilfrage.

Die bevorzugte Verwendung von Substantiven (bzw. Kombinationen von Substantiven und Verb) anstelle von Verben wird *Nominalstil* genannt und oft kritisiert. Trotzdem ist sie sehr verbreitet. Sie lässt einen Text oft sehr formal und technisch, ja bürokratisch erscheinen. Offenbar ist aber genau das oft gewünscht.

Der Nominalstil ist manchmal ökonomischer, weil er einen Nebensatz erspart. Das ist hier aber nicht der Fall, weil ein Partizip verwendet werden kann. Der Satz könnte aber auch mit einem Nebensatz formuliert werden: *Die Möglichkeiten bestehen unter Einhaltung der Regelungen des Rechnungslegungssystems, das angewandt wird*.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre ausführliche Erklärung! Das hilft mir! Und davon gehe ich aus, man die Wortgruppen von dem Norminalstil viel lesen und aufwendig lernen muss, oder?